# Anaconda Navigator not opening. "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: anaconda

I uninstalled and then reinstalled Anaconda. I am unable to launch the Navigator or Spyder (nothing happens when I click on them from the Start menu). When I try to launch from the terminal, I receive "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." and the issues below:

```
C:\Users\me\ anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 5, in (module)
  sys.exit(anaconda_navigator.app.main.main())
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 47, in main
  from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in (module)
  from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtGui.py", line 20 in (module)
  from PyQt5.QtGui import 8
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a 'clean' solution, but I managed to get Anaconda Navigator back on track by reinstalling the PyQT5 library.

I tried updating and installing it through anaconda prompt (comes preinstalled with your anaconda installation) at first, by typing:

```
conda update pyqt5
```

and later (when it said it wasn't found):

```
conda install pyqt5
```

but, sadly it couldn't locate any library named pyqt5 in their repository.

I had to go with:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

which is something I very much avoid, since conda and pip often don't work together well, but weirdly enough it solved the problem, at least for now.

Comment: Exactly same behavior. Worked for me as well: also, the same problem with conda install and had to go with pip, too. Thanks a lot, Бојан

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the most recent version of Anaconda. I installed it ~2 months ago and then one day Spyder failed to launch. I couldn't get Anaconda Navigator to launch either. I tried various fixes that folks mentioned, including

```
pip install PyQt5
```

And others. I clean reinstalled Anaconda like 5 or 6 times, deleted all of my files, upgrade Python to 5.11.x, etc. The only thing that got my Navigator and Spyder to launch again was running the command:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5==5.9
```

To which I was told:

```
Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.15.7
Uninstalling PyQt5-5.15.7:
Would remove:
```

....various files listed

I proceeded and was able to successfully boot navigator.